# Mini servo motor for a Furuta pendulum

Tags: control, servo, motor-controller

I am planning to build a [Furuta Pendulum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKzzWe15DEw). I have a mini-servo motor ([SG90 Mini Gear Micro 9g Servo RC](http://wiki.jmoon.co/motors/sg90/)). Within the scale shown in the video, is this mini-servo motor sufficient for this application?

Comment: If you increase the length of the rod and/or increase the radius then sure, but if you make an exact replica but with that servo motor you're proposing, then probably no. - Source => I got this servo next to me and it doesn't rotate nearly as fast as in the video, which I assume is required for it to work.

Comment: Many thanks Harry. From the control perspective, do think I have an enough resolution to control such an unstable system accurately?

Comment: As long as you take it apart and cut off the stub on the top gear and pull off the potentiometer's stub and solder two 10k resistors to replace the potentiometer, then we can keep talking. Because then you have a continues servo. (Which is what you need for the pendulum). And the resolution will be alright, because whatever control theory (PID?) you will be using, it will make it work. There's barely any information about the resolution (I haven't found any on the googlezor). But what I do know is that the resolution is higher than or equal to 1024 steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry. You may place your solution as an answer so I will accept it. BTW, if I need a continuous resolution to apply an LQR control will 1024 steps of Arduino be enough for such as control or should I switch to a different controller board?

Comment: Nah, you can't just trust one person, I could be super wrong. I'll let someone else answer. And yeah, an Arduino would be okay, but then you'd probably have to set up the servo PWM by yourself because the servo library that comes with the arduino software is utter shite. There's only 180 different values (8 bit-ish), for each degree when you use the servo as a servo & If you use the servo modified, as a continues servo. With both setups you can easily hear the values being sent to the servo. "Yes.. that's 44.. 43.. 42..", instead you should use proper timer interrupts and get like 10-16 bit.